# Comparing multiple values from a DataFrame against another of different shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-wrangling

#### Comparing values from a DataFrame agains another

Given the following data

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame({"Reference": ("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"), "Other col": ("U", "U", "U--","V", "W", "W--", "X", "Y")}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

truth_df = pd.DataFrame({"Reference": ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), "Other col": ("U", "V", "W", "X", "Y")}, index=[1, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

**data_df**

|  | Reference | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | U |
| 2 | A | U |
| 3 | A | Ux |
| 4 | B | V |
| 5 | C | W |
| 6 | C | Ww |
| 7 | D | X |
| 8 | E | Y |

**truth_df**

|  | Reference | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | U |
| 4 | B | V |
| 5 | C | W |
| 7 | D | X |
| 8 | E | Y |

I need to check and flag that the values in `data_df` match that of `truth_df` and hopefully end up with a new data set like:

**result_df**

|  | Reference | Value | Issues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | U |  |
| 2 | A | U |  |
| 3 | A | Ux | Wrong |
| 4 | B | V |  |
| 5 | C | W |  |
| 6 | C | Ww | Wrong |
| 7 | D | X |  |

Comment: `Apartment` isn't compared? So you're looking for in which column does Adddress, or PostCode differ for each group of /XX values?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected result?

Comment: Effectively yes that is correct, apologies if I didn't explain that properly, I can't rely on the Reference and Apartment, it is mostly Address and PostCode

Comment: @AndrejKesely, Sure thing, the last table is my expected result, where I add a new `Issues` column and name the column with the conflict

Comment: @wwnde absolutely right, but I don't want to give away sensitive information of real addresses, I'll try to create a small dummy dataset that will reflect my intentions

Comment: @AndrejKesely I just change the entire post, hopefully makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the dataframes with parameter `indicator=` set to `True`. If the indicator will be `left_only` means "Wrong" value in `Issue`:

```py
df_out = data_df.merge(
    truth_df, on=["Reference", "Other col"], how="left", indicator=True
).rename(columns={"_merge": "Issues"})

df_out["Issues"] = np.where(df_out["Issues"] == "left_only", "Wrong", "")

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Reference Other col Issues
0         A         U       
1         A         U       
2         A       U--  Wrong
3         B         V       
4         C         W       
5         C       W--  Wrong
6         D         X       
7         E         Y
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I manage to implement this to my code and is working fine, but I wonder is there a way to identify the columns that have the mismatch?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez You can try open new question here on StackOverflow. I can try to look at it.

Comment: Sure thing, I just did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67457473/how-to-get-pandas-df-merge-mismatch-column-name

Answer (score 2):

You can can create index by key column in both DataFrames with `set_index()` and then `reindex()` for same indices (columns names are same, so it's possible to compare). For example:

```py
df2 = df2.set_index('key')
df1 = df1.set_index('key').reindex(df2.index)
print(df1)
```

then compare:

```py
df3 = df1 != df2 
print(df3)
```

Comment: How about if all I need is to compare a set of my `df` against one row from `df_st`? this set will be the matching `References` so I would like to compare all matching `References` against its matching `Ref` in `df_st` `Address` and `PostCode` hope that makes sense

Comment: I have change the post to make it more clear, hopefully