# How to get Pandas df.merge() mismatch column name

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

Given the following data:

```py
data_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Reference": ("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
    "Value1": ("U", "U", "U--","V", "W", "W--", "X", "Y"),
    "Value2": ("u", "u--", "u","v", "w", "w", "x", "y")
    }, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
truth_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Reference": ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    "Value1": ("U", "V", "W", "X", "Y"),
    "Value2": ("u", "v", "w", "x", "y")
    }, index=[1, 4, 5, 7, 8])
```

**data_df**

|  | Reference | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | U | u |
| 2 | A | U | u-- |
| 3 | A | U-- | u |
| 4 | B | V | v |
| 5 | C | W | w |
| 6 | C | W-- | w |
| 7 | D | X | x |
| 8 | E | Y | y |

**truth_df**

|  | Reference | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | U | u |
| 4 | B | V | v |
| 5 | C | W | w |
| 7 | D | X | x |
| 8 | E | Y | y |

The code below merges both and flags the rows where the values don't match from `truth_df`

```py
df_out = data_df.merge(truth_df, on=['Reference', 'Value1','Value2'], how='left', indicator=True).rename(columns={"_merge":"Issues"})
df_out["Issues"] = np.where(df_out["Issues"] == "left_only", "Flag", "")
df_out
```

Yields the following dataframe

**df_out**

|  | Reference | Value1 | Value2 | Issues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | U | u |  |
| 1 | A | U | u-- | Flag |
| 2 | A | U-- | u | Flag |
| 3 | B | V | v |  |
| 4 | C | W | w |  |
| 5 | C | W-- | w | Flag |
| 6 | D | X | x |  |
| 7 | E | Y | y |  |

I would like to know if there is a way to identify which columns are in conflict, so instead of displaying `Flag` I'll display the column name like `Value1` and `Value2` respectively.

**desired df**

|  | Reference | Value1 | Value2 | Issues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | U | u |  |
| 1 | A | U | u-- | Value2 |
| 2 | A | U-- | u | Value1 |
| 3 | B | V | v |  |
| 4 | C | W | w |  |
| 5 | C | W-- | w | Value1 |
| 6 | D | X | x |  |
| 7 | E | Y | y |  |

**Please note** that even though the `Reference` column looks useful, it is not a reliable source in my real data, so any solutions must not use that column.

Comment: By comparing against the `truth_df`

Answer (score 4):

You can set index of both the dataframes as index using [**`df.set_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) then check for equality using [**`df.ne`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) then use [**`df.dot`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns.

```py
data_df = data_df.set_index('Reference') # Ignore if Reference is index already
truth_df = truth_df.set_index('Reference') # Ignore if Reference is index already
data_df['issue'] = data_df.ne(truth_df, axis=1).dot(data_df.columns)
print(data_df.reset_index())

  Reference Value1 Value2   issue
0         A      U      u        
1         A      U    u--  Value2
2         A    U--      u  Value1
3         B      V      v        
4         C      W      w        
5         C    W--      w  Value1
6         D      X      x        
7         E      Y      y
```

Comment: Yes like that but, is there another way without using the `Reference` column? I should have mention that in my post (I will change it) `Reference` is not a reliable column to use in with my real data

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

data_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Reference": ("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E"),
    "Value1": ("U", "U", "U--","V", "W", "W--", "X", "Y"),
    "Value2": ("u", "u--", "u","v", "w", "w", "x", "y")
    }, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
truth_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Reference": ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
    "Value1": ("U", "V", "W", "X", "Y"),
    "Value2": ("u", "v", "w", "x", "y")
    }, index=[1, 4, 5, 7, 8])

for col in data_df.columns:
    flaged = col

df_out = data_df.merge(truth_df, on=['Reference', 'Value1','Value2'], how='left', indicator=True).rename(columns={"_merge":"Issues"})
df_out["Issues"] = np.where(df_out["Issues"] == "left_only", flaged, "")
print(df_out)
```

Try this.

Comment: Thank you but it only Flags `Value2` as the columns and that is not the case on all of them

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (using the `df_out` you already have):

```py
def fn(x):
    truth_idx = truth_df["Reference"].eq(x["Reference"]).idxmax()
    if x["Value1"] == truth_df.at[truth_idx, "Value1"]:
        return "Value2"
    return "Value1"


m = df_out["Issues"] == "Flag"
df_out.loc[m, "Issues"] = df_out.loc[m, ["Reference", "Value1"]].apply(
    fn,
    axis=1,
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  Reference Value1 Value2  Issues
0         A      U      u        
1         A      U    u--  Value2
2         A    U--      u  Value1
3         B      V      v        
4         C      W      w        
5         C    W--      w  Value1
6         D      X      x        
7         E      Y      y
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the `Reference` column is not a reliable column in my real data so I cannot use it.